# Comparing sizes of sets that are keys and values of a map

Tags: java, dictionary, hash, set, key

> Consider a map  m, where  m  is of type  HashMap  or  TreeMap.  Suppose  s1  and  s2  are both sets, of type  HashSet  or  TreeSet, where  s1  is the set of keys in  m, and  s2 is the set of corresponding values in  m.  Which  must  be true?

a. s1.size() > s2.size()

b. s1.size() <= s2.size()

c. s1.size() >= s2.size()This is the correct answer.

d. s1.size() == s2.size()

e. s1.size() < s2.size()

I had thought it would be "b" since a key can have many values, but it turns out the answer is c, where there may be more keys than values. However, I'm having problems understanding the answer provided (c)—could anyone help me understand why b is wrong and c is right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A key can only have 1 value.  The value could be an object, that could contain multiple things.  But you only have 1 value per key.

In a Map your keys are guaranteed to be unique, but the values do not have to be unique.  In the following example there are 3 unique keys, but only 1 unique value:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("key1", "elephant");
map.put("key2", "elephant");
map.put("key3", "elephant");
```

So if you create a Set from the list of values, the only object in the Set will be "elephant".  But if you create a Set from the keys then you get 3 objects "key1", "key2", and "key3".  So the count of keys is greater than the count of values.

Answer (score 1):

You have it backwards: A key has at most one value of type `V`. (That `V` could be a container like a set or list, but it is a single value in the map.) Multiple keys could have the same value (this is in fact how `HashSet` itself is implemented, on top of a `HashMap`).